# How to “pronounce” punctuation symbols on .net

Tags: c#, speechsynthesizer

I am writing an application with voice duplication of UI messages (it is for blind and low-vision people).
The application will work with or without an internet connection, so I decided to use an internal SpeechSynthesizer. It looks like:

```
using (var synth = new SpeechSynthesizer())
{
    synth.Speak("! missed");
}
```

My issue, that SpeechSynthesizer doesn't pronounce punctuation symbols. So the text above sounds like "missed". I have a stupid (but working) solution - I am replacing all punctuation symbols with appropriate text:

```
"! missed".Replace("!","exclamation mark");//-> exclamation mark missed
```

It works, but I'm pretty sure there should be settings to set it up. Could anybody point me to this setting?

Comment: I would doubt it, because pronouncing punctuation would be highly contextual. "Hello comma my name is Johnny {full stop/ period}" - you likely wouldn't want either of these anyway, but the synth doesn't know that.

Comment: Doesn't Windows have built-in accessibility features for reading out text? Wouldn't it be better off left to that?

Comment: May be you could try adding lexicon that contains a custom pronunciation for ! as exclamation mark using  AddLexicon https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.speech.synthesis.speechsynthesizer.addlexicon?view=netframework-4.8

Comment: @LukeBriggs You are right, it sounds bad, but it is better than skipping important marks. I will check it with the tester and write the result.

Comment: @DavidG Yes, it has. But a user has to switch to specific window. I want to add a shortcut.

Comment: @Bharat Yes, I have read about lexicons. I looked for such implemented lexicon.

Comment: @RredCat, did it help? I mean do you try that part?